# Server 2012 Event ID 4625 An account failed to log on

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, login

I can' t login using one of my admin account. But i can loggin using Domain admin. Event Details are mentioned in below. please help me..

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          04-08-18 10:18:51 AM
Event ID:      4625
Task Category: Account Lockout
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Failure
User:          N/A
Computer:      SY9_DB.abc.com
Description:
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       DbAdmin
    Account Domain:     TOROID

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Account locked out.
    Status:         0xC0000234
    Sub Status:     0x0

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   SY9_UTL
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" />
    <EventID>4625</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>12546</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8010000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-08-04T04:48:51.007716800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>12092388</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="704" ThreadID="436" />
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>SY9_DB.abc.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetUserName">DpAdmin</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetDomainName">TOROID</Data>
    <Data Name="Status">0xc0000234</Data>
    <Data Name="FailureReason">%%2307</Data>
    <Data Name="SubStatus">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="LogonType">3</Data>
    <Data Name="LogonProcessName">NtLmSsp </Data>
    <Data Name="AuthenticationPackageName">NTLM</Data>
    <Data Name="WorkstationName">SY9_UTL</Data>
    <Data Name="TransmittedServices">-</Data>
    <Data Name="LmPackageName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="KeyLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessId">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="IpAddress">-</Data>
    <Data Name="IpPort">-</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Did you reset the password and ensure the account is unlocked?

Comment: From event details : `Failure Reason:     Account locked out.`

Comment: but i can logging to account once and once i run program automatically account get locked out. I can't found password issue at all.

Comment: What program are you running which locks the account ?  Is there a way you can pull the logs of that program ?

Comment: ERP db is running on this machine. It has no special errors found. finally i removed group policy and it works fine. But i want to implement it again